# how to save DOM insertions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, dom

I want to know how to save a previous DOM insertion of my HTML page.
Code:

```
//With jQuery
$('#container').append('Hi!');
```

And the window wil display `Hi!`, but I want to know how I could save that insertion to,when I refresh the page, display me 2 `Hi!`, being result of the previous insertion of the jQuery Mark.

**How I can save the changes in the HTML structure that  javascript do after executing the code(like the example below)?**

Comment: no easy way... use server-side code for that

Comment: Maybe an array in the server side?

Comment: Probably wouldn't be the best way (for reasons that everyone else is pointing out), but you could use window storage: http://www.diveintojavascript.com/javascript-apis/web-storage-dom-storage . Problems with this are that it is HTML5 only (although there are libraries that help support it), and that you can only store strings in (no arrays/objects), but you can use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, or the likes. Just an idea

Comment: just save the html of the container? ( you have to use server-side, or localstorage )

Answer (score 1):

You can save your status in many different ways.

1. Save in server (database or session whatever through AJAX)
2. Save in Cookies (You can save your data locally by accessing cookies in JavaScript)
3. Save in LocalStorage (This is part of HTML5, which means this does not work in non-modern browsers)